# Html Button Click in DotNet Core

Tags: c#, html, button, click

I want to login to my account on my providers page by clicking the login button and then getting the HTML.

For java I can use:

```
HtmlPage page = crawler.getWebClient().getPage(ProviderPage));
HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);

form.getInputByName("msisdn_msisdn").setValueAttribute("");
form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("");

page = form.getInputByValue("login").click();

System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

But in C# i cant find any class to make his possible. It has to be compatible with DotNet Core 2.0 or grater.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using Selenium.WebDriver, I used it with .NET Core 2.1 and it worked fine.

You just have to install the package from NuGet and you are ready to go.

Take a look at [this](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/) if you need help to select items from the document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.